# First exit time of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

I am new to stopping times and would appreciate any explanation on the following problem:

Let $τ(ω) =$ inf$\{t>0:|W_t(ω)| \geq K\}$, with $K > 0$ constant, be the stopping time. $W_t$ is the Brownian motion.

1. What does the following equation mean?
2. What is the intuition idea behind the following equation? (i.e. why is it true?)

$$\{ω : τ(ω)\leq t\} = \bigcup_{0<s<t}\{ω:|W_s(ω)|\geq K\}$$

This is what I gathered so far:

Since $τ(ω) =$ inf$\{t>0:|W_t(ω)| \geq K\}$, 
\begin{align}
\{ω:τ(ω) \leq t\} &= \tag{1}\left\{ω: \mathrm{inf}\{s>0:|W_s(ω)| \geq K\} \leq t \right\}\\
&= \tag{2}\bigcup_{0<s<t}\{ω:|W_s(ω)|\geq K\}
\end{align}

3. How does $(1)$ equal $(2)$?
4. How did the union come about and what happened to the infimum?

**EDIT** : Despite the 2 answers given, I still have trouble understanding.

Thank you.

Comment: It means the stopping time being less than $t$ is the same as Brownian motion exceeding $K$ at any time before $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equivalent are the statements:

- $\omega\in\bigcup_{s\in\left(0,t\right)}\left\{ |W_{s}|\geq K\right\} $
- For some $s\in\left(0,t\right)$ we have $|W_{s}\left(\omega\right)|\geq K$
- $\inf\left\{ s>0\mid |W_{s}\left(\omega\right)|\geq K\right\} <t$
- $\tau\left(\omega\right)<t$

Comment: thank you. However, may you explain why inf$\{s>0\} < t \iff 0 < s < t$?
This is what I understand from the 2nd to 3rd point

Comment: What I am actually saying is: if $s<t$ and $s\in A$ then $\inf A\leq s<t$ (do you agree?). This for the set $A=\{r>0\mid |W_r(\omega)|\geq K\}$.

Comment: I refined my question and your answer resolves point 2. However, may you assist me in point 3 and 4? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The stopping time $\tau(\omega)$ of one particular path $\omega$ is the time this path is further than $K$ away from the origin for the first time.

The line you are interested in says the collection of all paths with stopping time smaller than $t$ is the union over all $s$ smaller than $t$ of all path that at time $s$ are further than $K$ from the origin.

Edit: The left side of the equation is the collection of all paths that are further away than $K$ from the origin at least once before time $t$. So every path in this set needs to be further away than $K$ at some point $s$ with $0 < s < t$. For a fixed $s$, the term in brackets on the right side is the collection of paths that are further away than $K$ at time $s$. The union over all $s$ is exactly the collection of paths that are further away then $K$ at some point between $0$ and $t$.

Comment: I am having difficulties understanding the heuristic (not mathematical argument) as to why "The line you are interested in says the collection of all paths with stopping time smaller than t is the union over all s smaller than t of all path that at time s are further than K from the origin." 
Perhaps, may you elaborate farther? Thanks!

Comment: thank you for the edit. However, may you re-explain your first sentence of the edit? I still do not understand why does $\{ω:\mathrm{inf}\{s>0:|W_s(ω)| \geq K\} \leq t\}$ mean "at least once before time t" as stated in your first sentence of the edit.

Comment: The inner curly brackets contains all times where a specific path $\omega$ is farther away than $K$. The infimum is the first time it is farther away than $K$ so the whole things means, all paths whose first time farther away than $K$ is smaller than $t$.